# If a function (that's outside of the class) needs to use a method from a class, how do I call the method?

Tags: python, class, methods

Here's the class:

```
class MinerNotFullAction:
   def __init__(self, entity, image_store):
      self.entity = entity
      self.image_store = image_store

   def miner_to_ore(self, world, ore):
      entity_pt = entities.get_position(self.entity)
      if not ore:
         return ([entity_pt], False)
      ore_pt = entities.get_position(ore)
      obj = point.Point(0, 0)
      if obj.adjacent(entity_pt, ore_pt):
         entities.set_resource_count(self.entity,
            1 + entities.get_resource_count(self.entity))
         remove_entity(world, ore)
         return ([ore_pt], True)
      else:
         new_pt = next_position(world, entity_pt, ore_pt)
         return (worldmodel.move_entity(world, entity, new_pt), False)
```

And here's the function that's in the same file, but it's outside of the class:

```
def miner_not_full_action(world, action, ticks):
   entity = action.entity
   entity_pt = entities.get_position(entity)
   ore = find_nearest(world, entity_pt, entities.Ore)
   (tiles, found) = MinerNotFullAction.miner_to_ore(world, entity, ore)

   if found:
      entity = try_transform_miner(world, entity, try_transform_miner_not_full)

   schedule_action(world, entity,
      create_miner_action(entity, action.image_store),
      ticks + entities.get_rate(entity))
   return tiles
```

If you look at the function, `def miner_not_full_action`, you'll see the line: `(tiles, found) = miner_to_ore(world, entity, ore).` Notice that inside this function, it is calling the method, `miner_to_ore` (from the class that I've provided above).

My question is, what is the correct way to rewrite this line of code so that the function can use this method from the class (even though the function itself is outside of the class)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only call methods of a class from outside if you either have an object of this class or can construct one. Except, if it is a static method or a class method.

In your example, you want to use something from

```
class MinerNotFullAction:
   def __init__(self, entity, image_store):
      self.entity = entity
      self.image_store = image_store

   def miner_to_ore(self, world, ore):
       ...
```

in

```
def miner_not_full_action(world, action, ticks):
   entity = action.entity
   entity_pt = entities.get_position(entity)
   ore = find_nearest(world, entity_pt, entities.Ore)
   (tiles, found) = MinerNotFullAction.miner_to_ore(world, entity, ore)
   ...
```

So, the question is: Do you have an appropriate ection object here?

If so (`action` sounds like an appropriate candidate), you can do

```
(tiles, found) = action.miner_to_ore(world, ore)
```

in order to perform your task.

See it from the other side: If you call this method, you must have something to be seen as `self`. This should be an instance of this class. If you don't have anything like that, you have to create one. Otherwise, `self` would make no sense in that method.

Easy example:

```
def miner_not_full_action(world, action, ticks):
    # 1. call it via the class. That may or may not work, but you have to provide an action object as the first argument.
    try1 = MinerNotFullAction.miner_to_ore(action, world, ore)
    # 2. call it regularly (as already mentioned), equivalent to 1.
    try2 = action.miner_to_ore(world, ore)

    # If we don't have such an object? Then we create one:
    ac = MinerNotFullAction()
    # and use it to call:
    try3 = ac.miner_to_ore(world, ore)
```